# Any shortcut to automatically add a row item to TableView with Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, sidebar

Am a beginner learning IOS development. I have a sideBar that I created inside my storyboard with `tableView` and `ViewController`.I have set it up with constraints and all that. Screenshot:
[image]

After everything, I decided that I want to insert another row item just below the third one. I don't want to remove my constraints and start over again. Is there a way I can just duplicate one of the rows with constrains and edit it to add the new item?

Comment: Could you please clarify are you using one UITableViewCell for these rows or static cells or even something else? 
To be honest you wouldn't have such problem if you would use prototype reusable cell with properly configured dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Using UITableViewDatasource protocol

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```